plotly drill down a stacked-bar chart
I have a stacked bar chart which has class 10,11 12 in x axis and count of students in y axis .
in each bar count of male and female students are stacked .
i have another categorical column "Stay" having Hostel and Dayscholar as categories
i want to drill down .
Now for example :
when i click on a stack of any bar (whether male student of class 10),i want to show a plot of those male students which shows the stay graph of those male students.
I basically building a streamlit dashboard using plotly visualisations .Solutions arounds this would be appreciated
Help me with this : ) Thanks in advance .
I tried plotly_events to handle whenever user click on which stack of bar ,based on this it should so me chart .but dint work

It's really hard to help with your programming, when you didn't include it in your question. Try editing your post by making your problem reproducible for those that would like to help.
